# JSONModel: How to merge with existing data when calling "loadData"

Tags: sapui5

I have the following coding in my SAP UI5 application Controller:

```js
var myView = this.getView();
var data1 = { "myDate": new Date() };
oModel.loadData("products.json");
oModel.setData(data1);
myView.setModel(oModel);
```

Where *products.json* - just a simple data for the table on the screen.

And I can see only *products.json* data on the screen as a result, and *myDate* with empty value inside `oModel` (checked in debug).

In case I comment *loadData* string, *myDate* value is on the screen and looks good.

How I can use them together? What is the best practice for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model's `loadData` is an asynchronous process, so it will update the model after you have set it synchronously with `data1`.
Also, `setData()` will wipe everything already in the model, so better use `setProperty` and update only a specific node in your model.

You should add the static data once you have loaded it from file:

```
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    oModel.setProperty("/myExtraData", data1);
});
```

Your added date is then available via `/myExtraData/myData`

Answer (score 0):

Merge new data with existing one with [`bMerge`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#setData) parameter of `setData()`.

```
oModel.loadData("products.json");
var data1 = {
    "myDate": new Date()
};
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
   oModel.setData(data1, true);
});
```

Comment: I was aware about bMerge option, but it doesn't work without attachRequestCompleted function. Your example works fine, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The API [`loadData`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel#methods/loadData) has also a `bMerge` option.

```javascript
oModel.setData({ myDate: new Date() });
oModel.loadData("products.json", null, true, "GET", /*bMerge*/true);
```

> ```js
> // Merged results:
> {
>   myDate: /*date object*/,
>   produces: [/*...*/]
> }
> ```

No need to register an event handler for `requestCompleted`.